# Convert string to Pascal Case (aka UpperCamelCase) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, case

Id like to know how I can covert a string into a pascal case string in javascript (& most probally regex).

Conversion Examples:

- double-barrel = Double-Barrel
- DOUBLE-BARREL = Double-Barrel
- DoUbLE-BaRRel = Double-Barrel
- double barrel = Double Barrel

Check [this link](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase) for further info on Pascal Case

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
s = s.replace(/(\w)(\w*)/g,
        function(g0,g1,g2){return g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase();});
```

The regex finds words (here defined using `\w` - alphanumerics and underscores), and separates them to two groups - first letter and rest of the word. It then uses a function as a callback to set the proper case.

Example: http://jsbin.com/uvase

Alternately, this will also work - a little less regex and more string manipulation:

```
s = s.replace(/\w+/g,
        function(w){return w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1).toLowerCase();});
```

I should add this isn't pascal case at all, since you have word barriers (`helloworld` vs `hello-world`). Without them, the problem is almost unsolvable, even with a dictionary. This is more commonly called Title Case, though it doesn't handle words like "FBI", "the" or "McDonalds".

Comment: Spot on, although I think Title Case is different to Pascal Case (Uppercamelcase)

Title Case = Double-barrel
Pascal Case = Double-Barrel

Comment: Title case is potentially misleading. It has a distinct meaning that does not match normal English. Titlecase is a Unicode casing property, mostly used for when only the first letter should be capitalized. It applies to certain digraphs differently from other characters, such as the Ǳ vs ǲ vs ǳ. In contrast, proper casing of English titles works quite differently, ignoring short prepositions except when the first or last word, etc.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. Try to convert the string `fooBar` to `FooBar`, it will fail.

Comment: @RenanCoelho - That's harsh. There are may flavors of "convert to pascal case". In this one, the OP wanted to ignore the original case of the word - `DoUbLE` -> `Double`. If your scenario is different, I'm sure you can find a more suitable question.

Comment: It also won't work with diacritics.

Comment: Here is a one-line Typescript version of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068573/77132567#answer-77132567

Answer (score 38):

**Here's my suggestion:**

```
function toPascalCase(string) {
  return `${string}`
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(new RegExp(/[-_]+/, 'g'), ' ')
    .replace(new RegExp(/[^\w\s]/, 'g'), '')
    .replace(
      new RegExp(/\s+(.)(\w*)/, 'g'),
      ($1, $2, $3) => `${$2.toUpperCase() + $3}`
    )
    .replace(new RegExp(/\w/), s => s.toUpperCase());
}
```

or

```
String.prototype.toPascalCase = function() {
  return this
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(new RegExp(/[-_]+/, 'g'), ' ')
    .replace(new RegExp(/[^\w\s]/, 'g'), '')
    .replace(
      new RegExp(/\s+(.)(\w*)/, 'g'),
      ($1, $2, $3) => `${$2.toUpperCase() + $3}`
    )
    .replace(new RegExp(/\w/), s => s.toUpperCase());
};
```

**Test cases:**

```
describe('String to pascal case', function() {
  it('should return a pascal cased string', function() {
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('foo bar'), 'FooBar');
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('Foo Bar'), 'FooBar');
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('fooBar'), 'FooBar');
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('FooBar'), 'FooBar');
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('--foo-bar--'), 'FooBar');
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('__FOO_BAR__'), 'FooBar');
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('!--foo-¿?-bar--121-**%'), 'FooBar121');
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('Here i am'), 'HereIAm');
    chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('FOO BAR'), 'FooBar');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Just updated the function.

Comment: Boom! And the internet gets even better ;) @kalicki2k

Comment: A lot of thanks, works like charm on all of my needed cases ^^

Comment: Appears to have an issue with all capitalization (e.g. "FOO BAR"). The first word remains completely capital. Works for the first one if you change `${string}` to `_${string}` (least intrusive workaround I could find).

Comment: Does not work for 'FooBar' and 'fooBar'

Comment: This solution is almost perfect, it does not support accented characters like "ó", I've tried with the word 'Escritórios'

Answer (score 23):

In case dash, space and other are string separators one may use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#camelCase).

e.g.

```
_.upperFirst(_.camelCase('double-barrel')); // => DoubleBarrel
```

Comment: This only convert the first letter. It outputs `Double-barrel` instead of `DoubleBarrel`

Comment: Have you used _.camelCase? Please check the example once again

Comment: Great solution, works with `.` separators as well (i.e. `double.barrel` => `DoubleBarrel`)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toPascalCase (str) {
  if (/^[a-z\d]+$/i.test(str)) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  }
  return str.replace(
    /([a-z\d])([a-z\d]*)/gi,
    (g0, g1, g2) => g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase()
  ).replace(/[^a-z\d]/gi, '');
}
```

I started with [Kobi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068573/convert-string-to-pascal-case-aka-uppercamelcase-in-javascript#answer-4068586), and used the Chai tests from [kalicki2k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068573/convert-string-to-pascal-case-aka-uppercamelcase-in-javascript#answer-53952925) to kick the tires.

Crude multilingual support can be added by changing `a-z` to [`\p{L}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes), and adding the [`u` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#using_unicode_regular_expressions):

```js
function toPascalCase (str) {
  if (/^[\p{L}\d]+$/iu.test(str)) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  }
  return str.replace(
    /([\p{L}\d])([\p{L}\d]*)/giu,
    (g0, g1, g2) => g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase()
  ).replace(/[^\p{L}\d]/giu, '');
}
```

Two additional tests that only pass with the unicode-enabled version:

```js
chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('ça.roule'), 'ÇaRoule');
chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('добрий-день'), 'ДобрийДень');
```

Incidentally, the non-unicode version is roughly twice as fast as the unicode-version & kalicki2k's version. Which doesn't really matter, they are all plenty fast.

If you need caching:

```js
const pascalCache = {};
function toPascalCase (str) {
    pascalCache[str] =
        pascalCache[str] ||
        (
            /^[a-z\d]+$/i.test(str) &&
            str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
        ) ||
        str.replace(
            /([a-z\d])([a-z\d]*)/gi,
            (g0, g1, g2) => g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase()
        ).replace(/[^a-z\d]/gi, '');

    return pascalCache[str];
}
```

Caching plus multilingual:

```js
const pascalCache = {};
function toPascalCase (str) {
    pascalCache[str] =
        pascalCache[str] ||
        (
            /^[\p{L}\d]+$/iu.test(str) &&
            str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
        ) ||
        str.replace(
            /([\p{L}\d])([\p{L}\d]*)/giu,
            (g0, g1, g2) => g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase()
        ).replace(/[^\p{L}\d]/giu, '');

    return pascalCache[str];
}
```

These versions appear to be much faster (8x) in a benchmark, but of course that's not a good representation of real-world use.

Comment: If anyone is searching how to make acronyms go in pascal case as well, you can add this line to the function:       
`str = str.replace(/((?<=[A-Z])[A-Z]+)/g, (_, g1) => g1.toLowerCase())`,  
chai tests:      
`chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('BAR'), 'Bar');`
`chai.assert.equal(toPascalCase('fooBARfoo'), 'FooBarfoo');`

Comment: > toPascalCase('some-case_lol_whatIsThis')
'SomeCaseLolWhatisthis'
seems to be wrong ... because IsThis was already pascal case!

Answer (score 0):

A one-line Typescript version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068573/53952925#answer-4068586), which also handles the string being null/undefined:

```
const toPascalCase = (s: string | null | undefined) =>
  s ? s.replace(/(\w)(\w*)/g, (_, p, q) => p.toUpperCase() + q.toLowerCase()) : s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version with trim space option:

```js
const toPascalCase = (text, trimSpace=false) => text.split(' ').map((t) => t[0].toUpperCase() + t.slice(1).toLowerCase()).join(trimSpace?'':' ')
```

Tests:

```js
const toPascalCase = (text, trimSpace=false) => text.split(' ').map((t) => t[0].toUpperCase() + t.slice(1).toLowerCase()).join(trimSpace?'':' ')

console.log(toPascalCase('hello world')); // Output: "Hello World"
console.log(toPascalCase('foo bar baz')); // Output: "Foo Bar Baz"
console.log(toPascalCase('this is a sample text')); // Output: "This Is A Sample Text"
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const toPascalCase = (sentence) => sentence
   .toLowerCase()
   .replace(new RegExp(/[-_]+/, 'g'), ' ')
   .replace(new RegExp(/[^\w\s]/, 'g'), '')
   .trim()
   .split(' ')
   .map(word => word[0]
   .toUpperCase()
   .concat(word.slice(1)))
   .join('');

toPascalCase(words);
```

Comment: does not remove "_"