# XHTML Text input, CSS text-transform and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, text, alert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string to Pascal Case (aka UpperCamelCase) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068573/convert-string-to-pascal-case-aka-uppercamelcase-in-javascript)

I'm doing some quite basic stuff here so bear with me..

I'm using an XHTML text input to get a users name. I'm then showing an alert message via javascript. I've made it so that the first letters of the users names are capitalised via `text-transform: capitalize;` but javascript reads the original entry and doesn't take account of this.

What is the simplest solution I can use so that the alert is also capitalised in the same way? Preferably the less code the better so I can understand it easily :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var titleCase = 'make me look GOOD'.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)[a-z]/g, function(match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/cmMKg).

#### Output

```
Make Me Look Good
```