# How can I capitalize and remove spaces from a sentence/string?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache, assemble

I need this "get my first job" turn into this "GetMyFirstJob"

I am working with assemble http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-strings.html but I don't see something like that in the docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to Pascal Case (aka UpperCamelCase) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068573/convert-string-to-pascal-case-aka-uppercamelcase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper function and add the below code.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('toPascalCase', function(value) {
    return value.match(/[a-z]+/gi).map(function (word) {
      return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase()
    }).join('');
});
```

Call like

```
{{toPascalCase 'get my first job'}}
```